# Studying convergence/divergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Study the convergence/divergence of 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!}$$

So far, I've managed to break it down to:
$$U_n=\frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!}$$

But I can't judge a way how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: For $a\geq 0$ and $x>0$ you can determine convergence by the direct comparison test with $\hat{U}_n=\frac{n^nx^n}{n!}$ for $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Hint: Can you solve the case $a=0$ using Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a$ is unimportant (why?). Now try to use the limit comparison test and Stirling's Approximation.

Comment: :please tell why a is neglected?

Comment: @KD Use the limit comparison test with the function when $a=0$. You get something that tends towards a constant in terms of $n$ and $x$.